# QGIS Layers panel legend symbols are very large

Tags: qgis

I'm still working on version 3.4.15-Madeira but would like to update to a higher version. But from version 3.28 to the latest version, the Layers panel legend symbols are very large. Very unworkable if the map composition becomes complex. This happens with categorized classification of polygon layers, line layers have just a wider symbol and point layers are fine.

So I'll stick with 3.4. But now I want to go further to explore the new functionalities. Does anyone have an idea what causes this?

System is mac studio ventura.
[image]

Comment: Did you try to go to Setting>Option>Canvas&Legend and set a lower Maximum legend symbol size ?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you. But that does only affect real 'symbols' like dot, square or airport or so, not the default polygon square (which isn't really a symbol).